# is it possible to set adapter to linear layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview

Is it possible to set adapter to a `LinearLayout`?

I don't want to use `ListView` since I am using `ScrollView`.
so I am using `LinearLayout`...

In that I am dynamically adding views and now I need to use adapter..
so anybody have any suggestions?

I am doing this...

```
LinearLayout clientList = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.clients);
adapter = new Sample1AdapterActivity(this, arrayList);
View list = (ListView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.user_details, getListView(), false);
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

no you can't. What you can do is inflate the single row, and adding to the LinearLayout. In pseudo code:

```
  LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(...);
  LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
  for (item in arrayList) {
     View view  = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, linearLayout, false); 
     // set item content in view
     linearLayout.addView(view)
  }
```

Comment: You can benefit from some adapter niceties with my code above (for instance layout refresh when adapter gets updated).

Comment: It is definitely possibile but you pay the effort of write also the adapter. And in a custom getView you have to inflate and fill up the layout in any case. +1 from me @MarvinLabs

Comment: its working....but can i do some further operations on it? like onClick event handling etc.?

Comment: yes you can call setOnClickListener on every inflated view (if it this  what you meant)

Comment: but how can i set different items to different row view? that is from "for(items in arrayList)" , how can i make use of it? because i have multiple items on single row..i.e text, image, button...

Comment: in the same way. You can have R.layout.row1 and R.layout.row2, and inflate the former or the latter depending on the current item. About the for-loop it is just pseudo-code.

Comment: I wrote that special LinearLayout because I had an adapter that was already coded for another fragment for a ListView. And thus I was able to reuse that code inside a new Fragment which was embedding a limited amount of views within a scrollView. 

If you don't have any ListView anywhere, for sure you may simply just go with simple view inflation.

Comment: @shashi2459 it's not working for me. Can you please share your coed with me? Thanks!

Answer (score 20):

Yes you can by adding your own specific LinearLayout implementation to get child views from the adapter. However, my basic implementation will not provide all the view recycling code provided by the list view.

```
/**
 * A linear layout that will contain views taken from an adapter. It differs
 * from the list view in the fact that it will not optimize anything and
 * draw all the views from the adapter. It also does not provide scrolling.
 * However, when you need a layout that will render views horizontally and
 * you know there are not many child views, this is a good option.

 *
 * @author Vincent Mimoun-Prat @ MarvinLabs
 */
public class AdapterLinearLayout extends LinearLayout {

    private Adapter adapter;
    private DataSetObserver dataSetObserver = new DataSetObserver() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged() {
            super.onChanged();
            reloadChildViews();
        }
    };

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    public AdapterLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    }

    public AdapterLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    }

    public AdapterLinearLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    }

    public void setAdapter(Adapter adapter) {
        if (this.adapter == adapter) return;
        this.adapter = adapter;
        if (adapter != null) adapter.registerDataSetObserver(dataSetObserver);
        reloadChildViews();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
        super.onDetachedFromWindow();
        if (adapter != null) adapter.unregisterDataSetObserver(dataSetObserver);
    }

    private void reloadChildViews() {
        removeAllViews();

        if (adapter == null) return;

        int count = adapter.getCount();
        for (int position = 0; position < count; ++position) {
            View v = adapter.getView(position, null, this);
            if (v != null) addView(v);
        }

        requestLayout();
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer! But one question - as an android noob, can you tell me why setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL); seems to override the orientation VERTICAL I provided in XML? Some sort of precedence?