# Run Time add the button and lable in xamarin and android

Tags: c#-4.0, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am developing an android app in which i want to create an "N" number of button and Text box. Button having name "CALL" and Lable having mobile Number. when I click on call it make a call.

initializing the application like this way.

1) Initially when app is launch there is 1 text box for to enter mobile no and 1 button like "Add" => click on it => it run time generate multiple number of Lable for mobile no and buttons to make a call.

I new to this android development anybody can help me....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `RecyclerView` for this. You have to create a item template that contains the TextBox and the Button. And your Adapter holds the data model.
This tutorial is a good starting point: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/recyclerview/

Comment: any other alternative to do this

Comment: ListView or LinearLayout. The LinearLayout way, would shift the responsibility to create a view to you. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24905387/1489968